# How to Cast the DisplayObject into MediaElement in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mediaelement, osmf, displayobject

Is it possible to Cast the DisplayObject into MediaElement.Am trying to add the DisplayObject into the MediaContainer, but I got the following error:

> -1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:Loader to an unrelated type org.osmf.media:MediaElement.
>   -mediaContainer

_loader is the variable of `DisplayObject`.

```
mediaContainer.addMediaElement(_loader);
```

How can I rectify this problem? I am using Flash Builder4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add descendants of the MediaElement class using `MediaContainer.addMediaElement()`.  A Loader is not related to MediaElement, so it cannot be added directly.  Instead, you will need to create a MediaElement and add your Loader as a trait.  This requires you to use one of the OSMF loading classes instead, and which one you choose will depend on the type of content you are loading.

Comment: am Trying,i got Error like This.Error:The direct addition or removal of display objects onto a MediaContainer is prohibited.
 at org.osmf.containers::MediaContainer/addChild()

Comment: and also i tried to Cast Like this MediaContainer.addMediaElement(_loader as MediaElement);No Error,Nothing Displayed in the Screen

Comment: You won't be able to cast it because they are not related classes.  It seems that you need to create a MediaElement from your loaded content.

Comment: You can't. You need to load your content using an OSMF loader that can be used to create a MediaElement.

Comment: Am loading my Display Object using loader only sir